# In Android, override a method using Button onClick

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've got a Main Activity which is a search interface, when the user clicks a result in the list, the result details are displayed in a `Fragment`. The Main Activity has an Action Bar, but in the details Fragment, the Action Bar is hidden. To hide the Action Bar in the Fragment, I'm calling a method in the Main Activity from the Fragment Activity like this: `((SearchInterface)getActivity()).hideABar();`. Then when the user clicks the back button, they go back to the search interface and the Action Bar reappears. Doing that is a bit more complex than simply calling a method. I set up an `Interface` in the Main Activity and override the method in the Fragment like this:
**Main Activity:**

```
    public interface Callback {
    public void onBackPressedCallback();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if(fragBackPressed != null)
        fragBackPressed.onBackPressedCallback();
    checkActionBarState();
}

...


public void checkActionBarState(){
    bar_AB = getSupportActionBar();
    boolean barVisible = bar_AB.isShowing();
    if(barVisible){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ActionBar WAS Visible",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ActionBar WAS NOT Visible",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        bar_AB.show();
    }

}
```

**Fragment:**

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressedCallback() {
    Log.d("SSIVideoFrag", "checking action bar state");

}
```

So now, when the user presses the Back button while in the Details Fragment, they go back to Main Activity and the Action Bar reappears. Now I'd like to add a button in the Details Fragment that does what clicking the Back button does, but I can't figure out how to do it. I don't know how to override the `onBackPressedCallback()` method from within the onClick of a Button:

```
back_BTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //--- what to do here?


        }
    });
```

Comment: Calling `onBackPressed();` it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple:

`getFragmentManager().popBackStack();`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack()

ps.: that's not an actual back press, your `onBackPressed` will not be called. But the fragment will be removed, just like in a back press.

Comment: If you are creating the Fragment programmatically, use the addToBackStack(null) method when you replace the Fragment so your previous state will be added to the backstack.

Comment: Thank you, popBackStack was the answer. I just had to also add my `.checkActionBarState();` method to the button so that the Action Bar would be visible in the Main Activity.